# find the Laplace transform of a piecewise function using the graph

Tags: laplace-transform

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/72U2f.jpg)

what is the Laplace transform of the function shown in the graph above.
note that I tried to write the function in terms of the unit step function $u(t)=1$ if $t\ge 0$ and $u(t)=0$ if $t<0$. But I get I different answer from the doctor. Also I didn't understand how to write the function of the piece that is parallel to the y-axis.
Here is the solution of the doctor
$$f(t)= a.u(t)-t.u(t)+(t-a).u(t-a)-a.u(t-2a)+(t-2a).u(t-2a)-(t-3a).u(t-3a)$$

Comment: Use LaTeX please. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Might be helpful if you write the graph as sum of characteristic functions
$$(a-t)\chi_{[0,a]}(t)\ +(t-a)\chi_{[a,2a]}(t)\ +(t-2a)\chi_{[2a,3a]}(t)\ +a\chi_{[3a,\infty]}(t)$$
with $\chi_{[a,b]}(t)=u_a(t)-u_b(t)$.

Comment: i did the same way that you write it but the answer of the doctor is different